# Draggable date range using Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, highcharts

does anyone know of any drag events that can be used on a column chart created using Highcharts.js or even how to potentially mimic that event over the chart?

We have a split column chart. The smaller lower chart controls the date range on the master chart above. Currently the only way to adjust the range is to click and select segments of the smaller chart. Image below is what we have so far:

[image]

We would like to be able to make a draggable interface with handles to stretch and adjust the segment either way.

There is identical functionality in Highstock.js (screenshot below):
[image]

Comment: Could you make a http://JSFiddle.net with what you have currently? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In highcharts you can use only master-details type of chart http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-master-detail/

But you have ability to use highstock.js and use column chart in navigator / serie. Take look at example

http://jsfiddle.net/UNBP7/

```
navigator:{
            series:{
                type:'column'
            }
        },
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series