# Highcharts- How to create streaming bar charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts and I need to create one for reporting purposes. So creating one is simple but seems like the one they asked is not very simple at all. It should be something like a streaming graph where if something comes in it will start plotting until it is done.

So the scenario is like this.

1. It needs to be a column chart/columnrange type.
2. The x-axis will be the time. And should be moving from right to left. In 1 second or 2 seconds interval. Doesn't really matter.
3. So if the data comes in, let's say a call comes in. The time it comes it should start ploting/Drawing the bar until the call is done.
4. And it should be able to see the stock. Pretty much like the one in here http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/ where you can select a range and zoom in to that range.

I hope I'm making my scenario clear enough. Any reply is appreciated.

Best

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't provided any code to go with, the response here is going to be more of a guidance for you to do further research:

1. Select chart type to be a column
2. N/A
3. Since you're using jquery, if the data is coming in a json format - check out $.getJSON otherwise check out $.ajax or similar functions for you to get the data dynamically. You will then need to go through [Series.addPoint()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint%28%29)
4. Was already asked on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543594/draggable-date-range-using-highcharts-js)

Answer (score 0):

I think this example is pretty much what you wan to achieve. Only change series type to 'column', see: http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server.htm